# Javascript Scroll by one pixel on load of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using a mixture of jQueryTools overlay (lightbox type thing) and a scroll-bar called Perfect Scrollbar. The problem I have is that when the overlay is loaded the scroll-bar doesn't show until you scroll within that box. I need to be able to make it clearer so that everyone knows it is a scroll-able content box. One way this could be possible is to make the content box scroll up one pixel when the overlay is opened. I have found the following code

```
$(".scroll-content").load(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0,-1);
}
```

which I have been told should work but no matter what I can't get it to scroll at all.. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `overflow-y:auto` on that same overlay?

Comment: @ricohete Yes I have done but with no avail..

Comment: Can you link a page that is affected by the issue?

Comment: @GiacomoPaita http://dev.hostuk.org/team/

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the scroll bar method bind to an element that is initially in a 'hide' status, in fact `.BigSuperBlock .block_overlay` is hidden by `display:none;` in Css, the plugin can not properly calculate the height of the overlay container.

So, when you call the function that show-up the 'overlay' container, you have to call the method on the `scroll-content` class:

```
$('.scroll-content').perfectScrollbar('update');
```

You can find the [documentation](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/issues/127) of this in the author's page.

To make it works, you have to call the plugin 'update' method, again, in the jQueryTools modal function, as a **callback**.

```
 $(".block_overlay").overlay({ 
   onLoad: function(event) { 
      $('.scroll-content').perfectScrollbar('update'); 
      // here you update the perfectScrollbar plugin 
   }, 
   onClose: function(event) { 
   // other custom code 
   } 
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".block_overlay").overlay({
   mask : '#fff',
   left: 'center'
  });
 });`

This is the function I use to call the overlay.. how would I incorporate the scrollbar update in to that?

Comment: Try to find in the `overlay` plugin documentation the call-back function to call when the overlay is opened.

Comment: Unfortunately the website is down but I think you might mean this part - `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel]").overlay({
     mask : '#fff',
     top : 100,
    });
   });`

Comment: It might be something like:  `$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".block_overlay").overlay({
  mask : '#fff',
  left: 'center',
  callBackFunction: callBackFunction
 });
});`. But, again, read the Docs.

Comment: Here is i found an example, even if the site is offline: $("a[rel]").overlay({     onLoad: function(event) {      $('.scroll-content').perfectScrollbar('update');   // paste the scrollbar code     },     onClose: function(event) {         // other custom code    } });

Comment: by scrollbar code do you mean the update code or the code that initialises it? I've tried both and neither seem to work!

Comment: I've made an update in the comment, the scrollbar code is: $('.scroll-content').perfectScrollbar('update');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58243/discussion-between-giacomo-paita-and-joshuabrand).

Comment: @JoshuaBrand: did you eventually fixed the issue?

Comment: Hello, yeah I managed to find a little work around! I changed the overlay to display:block and gaze it a z-index of -999. This seemed to work as I'm guessing it loads overlay behind the page and once clicked it just brings it to the front! Thank for all your help though!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! However, if you think that my solution could be useful, could you mind to add an 'upvote' to it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 jQuery("container").animate({ scrollTop: 50 }, 800);
```

Answer (score -1):

Give that you want to make clear that there is a scrollbar, you can have it on all the time if you change the `perfect-scrollbar.css`

```
.ps-container .ps-scrollbar-x-rail {
    ...
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.ps-container .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {
    ...
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: I have done this and it works for when I use the scrollbar outside of the overlay I am wanting to produce it in but once I put it inside the overlay it doesn't seem to load the scrollbar at all until I scroll...

Comment: Hum... in fact if I reopen an overlay, the scrollbar is already visible. I also get a JS error on the page: `loaded is not defined`.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that if you re-open it it's still their from the previous time you've opened it... really need it to be there the first time of opening though!

Comment: Because the overlay is in `display:none;` status when you call the ScrollBar plugin.

Comment: Try adding `display: inherit` to the `ps-scrollbar-y-rail` css class.